# Missing artifact com.google.android.google-play-services:google-play-services:jar: 1

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I have created Android Project and then converted into Android-Maven Project. Then, I installed/downloaded required dependencies. However, after installing/downloading them, I am getting this error

> Missing artifact
>   com.google.android.google-play-services:google-play-services:jar:1

I don't know whats going wrong here. I am posting my `pom.xml` below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source/>
              <target/>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.google.api</id>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client</url>
        </repository>
        </repositories>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>.....</groupId>
                    <artifactId>.....</artifactId>
                    <version>...</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>.....</groupId>
                    <artifactId>.....</artifactId>
                    <version>...</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-api-client-android</artifactId>
                    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

I am attaching screenshot for reference. I tried all the questions and answers which are related to this on SO but not getting it done.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

I tried adding below code and some other SO ways but didn't work.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gsm</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>3</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think you need to install google play services in your sdk.

Comment: I have already installed it by android sdk

Comment: Since this issue looks urgent for you, Just as a worst case, you could always download the jar and use it right?

Comment: No. The problem is when add specific JAR it redirects to pointing play service JAR importing. Hence, I need to solve it